# Grails Datatables and Tomcat Selection does not work

Tags: tomcat, grails, datatables

I have included datatables in my project and it's working fine in my Netbeans environment but when deployed on the server running Tomcat I found that the selection does not work.

What I think can be the problem is that some stylesheets and javascript for the datatables does not load/execute correctly. But I can't see whats wrong.

Firefox console gives the following output:

```
--GET https://localhost:8443/assets/datatables.min.css [HTTP/1.1 404  3ms]
--GET https://localhost:8443/assets/select.datatables.min.css [HTTP/1.1 404  3ms]
GET https://localhost:8443/assets/buttons.dataTables.min-7e558a204ec7fa5a1fe03ae566b8435e.css [HTTP/1.1 200  0ms]
GET https://localhost:8443/assets/fixedColumns.dataTables.min-24c93cada3bc21d88bead6b23be16b0a.css [HTTP/1.1 200  0ms]
GET https://localhost:8443/assets/application-0a138929c6581e9b5ed8ee85ca53025e.js [HTTP/1.1 200  0ms]
GET https://localhost:8443/assets/fxHeader_0.6-4d5e0300e146fd4075dc4f2fedc4e720.js [HTTP/1.1 200  0ms]
GET https://localhost:8443/assets/datatables.min-261560cc9177118ee4aeb488982f1c8c.js [HTTP/1.1 200  0ms]
--GET https://localhost:8443/assets/datatables.select.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404  3ms]
GET https://localhost:8443/assets/dataTables.buttons.min-b5f969e77a600b78c50648e496f75942.js [HTTP/1.1 200  0ms]
GET https://localhost:8443/assets/buttons.html5.min-d4519ca89ec8fdf9f629d6d4329d9e92.js [HTTP/1.1 200  0ms]
GET https://localhost:8443/assets/dataTables.fixedColumns.min-d81dfe4ada44ad9df82986d4cb54dfd2.js [HTTP/1.1 200  0ms]
```

3 of them gives 404 in return and marked them with "--" in front.

Besides adding the stylesheets and scripts to the asset folder I load them in the head of the main.gsp:

```
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
<asset:stylesheet src="datatables.min.css"/>
<asset:stylesheet src="select.datatables.min.css"/>
<asset:stylesheet src="buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
<asset:stylesheet src="fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css"/>
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
<asset:javascript src="fxHeader_0.6.js"/>
<asset:javascript src="datatables.min.js"/>   
<asset:javascript src="datatables.select.min.js"/>   
<asset:javascript src="dataTables.buttons.min.js"/>   
<asset:javascript src="buttons.html5.min.js"/>   
<asset:javascript src="dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"/>
```

Isn't that enough? At least it's enough when I run it with run-app.

I got this from the firefox console:
Sorry it's in swedish ("Loading failed for Script with source" )

```
Laddning misslyckades för <script> med källan “https://wng.se/assets/datatables.select.min.js”.  woodtrading.se:19
Laddning misslyckades för <script> med källan “https://wng.se/DataTables-1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js”.  wng.se:26
TypeError: D is undefined  application-0a138929c6581e9b5ed8ee85ca53025e.js:255:214
Laddning misslyckades för <script> med källan “https://wng.se/FixedColumns-3.2.3/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js”.  wng.se:27
Laddning misslyckades för <script> med källan “https://wng.se/assets/datatables.select.min.js”.  list:19
e is null  content.js:25
Laddning misslyckades för <script> med källan “https://wng.se/ordersAndStore/DataTables-1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js”.  list:26
Laddning misslyckades för <script> med källan “https://wng.se/ordersAndStore/FixedColumns-3.2.3/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js”.  list:27
```

And if I inspect the head of the page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <title>
            Product buffer List
        </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application-47115a1aa0ee3cf9b02d0f362fbb8ded.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/datatables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/select.datatables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/buttons.dataTables.min-7e558a204ec7fa5a1fe03ae566b8435e.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fixedColumns.dataTables.min-24c93cada3bc21d88bead6b23be16b0a.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/application-0a138929c6581e9b5ed8ee85ca53025e.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/fxHeader_0.6-4d5e0300e146fd4075dc4f2fedc4e720.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/datatables.min-261560cc9177118ee4aeb488982f1c8c.js" ></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/datatables.select.min.js" ></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/dataTables.buttons.min-b5f969e77a600b78c50648e496f75942.js" ></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/buttons.html5.min-d4519ca89ec8fdf9f629d6d4329d9e92.js" ></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/dataTables.fixedColumns.min-d81dfe4ada44ad9df82986d4cb54dfd2.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Selection of what?

Comment: Selection of rows, you set the table option "select":true. It just like I removed the option.

Comment: Are the offending stylesheets in the same location as the others i.e. not in subfolders & are they setup the same in application.css? Also have you tried a hard refresh F5

Comment: Yes they are in the assets.javascripts and assets.stylesheets folders. But what do you mean with "hard refresh F5"? Where can I do that?

Comment: Sorry ctrl + F5, http://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/

Comment: No, that didn't help. I have not done as in application.css but I load them all in the head of main.gsp, added code in my question.

Comment: I added some more info in my question, you can see there that the page doesn't reference the scripts and stylesheets correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157138/discussion-between-mike-w-and-larand).

Comment: Have you tried using the war.original file instead of the war file.  We ran into a problem recently caused by the Spring Boot changes to the war and then running on Tomcat.

Comment: Yes, I have, but in my case, I have failed to name the files with correct case. I think it was a stylesheet named select.dataTables.min.css that I named select.datatables.min.css and that worked in NetBeans and grails run-app but not when it was deployed to run on TomCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by naming the scripts and stylesheets with correct case. When running by run-app it doesn't seem to be case sensitive, at least not if you're working in windows, but that Tomcat is case sensitive even if it runs in windows.
Thank's for all help!